# Replace function in main module from imported module in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Is it possible to set a global variable in the main module from an imported module (using a string) in python?

(Yes I know this isn't best practice.)

Ultimately I want it to look something like this:

`main.py`

```
import mod
def func():
  print('failure')
mod.run(func)
func()
```

`mod.py`

```
def func2():
    print('success')
def run(f):
    globals()[f.__name__] = func2
```

The result is `'failure'` because global is relative to the module.

I'm wanting to overwrite the variable `func` with `func2`, from the module.

Another caveat: the variable `func` changes, so I need to refer to it be the `f.__name__ string`

I'm aware that this approach wouldn't work if the name of `func` were changed before it's changed via `mod.run(func)`.

**My question:**  Is it possible to change the function in the main module from an imported module, without changing the code in the above example `main.py`?  If so, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than change what the name `func` is bound to, you can change the code that function `func` is bound to actually executes.

```
def func2():
    print('success')
def run(f):
    f.__code__ = func2.__code__
```

This modifies the actual function object referenced by `func`, and only partially using the code above, so further surgery may be needed (e.g. to update `func.__name__` to be `func2` instead of `func`), and you may want to make a real copy of `func` before monkey patching it like this.

Comment: the code would actually be f.__code__ = func2__code__
But that accomplishes "what I was really trying to do."

Comment: Ah, yes, `func_code` was the old 2.x name for the same attribute. (I forget when `__code__` was introduced, but it's available in 2.7 as well as 3.x, at least.)

Comment: Thanks for the help though, I understood what you meant and would probably still be struggling with this problem otherwise.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when there are free vars involved, such as from a wrapped function.

Comment: That's one of the things I glossed over with my "further surgery" comment. When a function is defined, it saves a reference to the global dictionary, where free variables will be looked up. You'd have to update that with `f.__globals__ = func2.__globals__`.

Comment: (Note that there is probably a way to accomplish what you originally tried, changing what `func` actually refers to rather than monkey-patching the object that `func` refers to) using `exec`. I made a couple of half-hearted attempts to do that before I gave up and suggested the above.)

Comment: `f.__globals__` and `f.__closure__` are readonly attributes, so it looks like monkey patching isn't an option when free vars are involved.

Comment: wrapped functions do not have `f.__code__`, but we can use `inspect.unwrap(f).__code__`